# Android Studio Version Build Codes

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Everytime I attempt to "Make" my project in Android Studio. I keep receiving this compilation error:

> Error:(1469,57) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable JELLY_BEAN
>     location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES

I am using Android Studio 0.4.2

Comment: What is your compileSdkVersion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JELLY_BEAN` is added in version codes after API level 16

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#JELLY_BEAN

So Make sure your compileSdkVersion is 16 or higher in build.gradle file. It is defined in build.gradle file like

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 16     // 16 or Higher
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'
    .............
}
```

Comment: Should you not still be able to do this?  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) It seems the problem came with a new Studio version...